# How to copy a plot into the clipboard for pasting?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, copy, clipboard

In running the below reproducible code, the user can select to view either the actual data or a plot of the data via a click of the radio button at the top of the rendered Shiny screen (as coded it defaults to data). At the bottom of the rendered screen you'll see a "Copy" button. By selecting "Data" and then "Copy", you can easily paste the data into XLS.

However, if the user instead selects to view the plot, I'd like the user to also be able to copy/paste the plot in the same manner. How can this be done?

I've tried inserting `plotPNG(...)` inside the `capture.output(...)` function (and various iterations thereof) in the below `observeEvent(...)`, using conditionals triggered by a conditional if `input$view == 'Plot'`, but with no luck yet.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
   radioButtons("view",
                label = "View data or plot",
                choiceNames = c('Data','Plot'),
                choiceValues = c('Data','Plot'),
                selected = 'Data',
                inline = TRUE
                ),
   conditionalPanel("input.view == 'Data'",tableOutput("DF")),
   conditionalPanel("input.view == 'Plot'",plotOutput("plotDF")),
   actionButton("copy","Copy",style = "width:20%;")
)
  
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- data.frame(Period = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),Value = c(10,20,15,40,35,30))

  output$DF <- renderTable(data)
  output$plotDF <- renderPlot(ggplot(data, aes(Period,Value)) + geom_line())

  observeEvent(
    req(input$copy),
    writeLines(
      capture.output(
        write.table(
          x = data,
          sep = "\t",
          row.names = FALSE
          )
        ),
      "clipboard")
    )
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can simply embed your plot in `ggplotly()`, it will display a camera icon to copy the plot (and add nice interaction with the plot)

Comment: You also can use `DT` instead of base table. It has an embedded Copy button (and many other interactive features)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on Edge.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

js <- '
async function getImageBlobFromUrl(url) {
  const fetchedImageData = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await fetchedImageData.blob();
  return blob;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#copybtn").on("click", async () => {
    const src = $("#plotDF>img").attr("src");
    try {
      const blob = await getImageBlobFromUrl(src);
      await navigator.clipboard.write([
        new ClipboardItem({
          [blob.type]: blob
        })
      ]);
      alert("Image copied to clipboard!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.name, err.message);
      alert("There was an error while copying image to clipboard :/");
    }
  });
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  br(),
  actionButton("copybtn", "Copy", icon = icon("copy"), class = "btn-primary"),
  br(),
  plotOutput("plotDF")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["plotDF"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(
      iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)
    ) + geom_point()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

Alerts are not nice. I suggest **shinyToastify** instead.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyToastify)
library(ggplot2)

js <- '
async function getImageBlobFromUrl(url) {
  const fetchedImageData = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await fetchedImageData.blob();
  return blob;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#copybtn").on("click", async () => {
    const src = $("#plotDF>img").attr("src");
    try {
      const blob = await getImageBlobFromUrl(src);
      await navigator.clipboard.write([
        new ClipboardItem({
          [blob.type]: blob
        })
      ]);
      Shiny.setInputValue("success", true, {priority: "event"});
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.name, err.message);
      Shiny.setInputValue("failure", true, {priority: "event"});
    }
  });
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  useShinyToastify(),
  br(),
  actionButton("copybtn", "Copy", icon = icon("copy"), class = "btn-primary"),
  br(),
  plotOutput("plotDF")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["plotDF"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(
      iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)
    ) + geom_point()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["success"]], {
    showToast(
      session,
      input,
      text = tags$span(
        style = "color: white; font-size: 20px;", "Image copied!"
      ),
      type = "success",
      position = "top-center",
      autoClose = 3000,
      pauseOnFocusLoss = FALSE,
      draggable = FALSE,
      style = list(
        border = "4px solid crimson",
        boxShadow = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56) 0px 22px 30px 4px"
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input[["failure"]], {
    showToast(
      session,
      input,
      text = tags$span(
        style = "color: white; font-size: 20px;", "Failed to copy image!"
      ),
      type = "error",
      position = "top-center",
      autoClose = 3000,
      pauseOnFocusLoss = FALSE,
      draggable = FALSE,
      style = list(
        border = "4px solid crimson",
        boxShadow = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56) 0px 22px 30px 4px"
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: When I run this it fails to copy. Either running your original code or edited code using shinyToastify package.  I tried adding libraries for htmlTable, htmltools, htmlwidgets, and shinyjs, and none of them make it work. Is there possibly some other library() I need to run this?

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 What is the browser you use? And do you use the same ids (copybtn and plotDF)?

Comment: My default browser is Edge. I also just ran your Edited code and it works fine if I select "Open in browser". Otherwise I get the "Failed to copy" notice

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 Ah yes, it probably doesn't work in the RStudio browser.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent. What could be the reason that your edited code with `shinyToastify` works without problems in Edge but not in Firefox? All browser are uptodate.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `shinyscreenshot`: You can further tweak it https://daattali.com/shiny/shinyscreenshot-demo/

Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyscreenshot)


ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("view",
               label = "View data or plot",
               choiceNames = c('Data','Plot'),
               choiceValues = c('Data','Plot'),
               selected = 'Data',
               inline = TRUE
  ),
  div(
    id = "takemyscreenshot",
  conditionalPanel("input.view == 'Data'",tableOutput("DF")),
  conditionalPanel("input.view == 'Plot'",plotOutput("plotDF")),
  actionButton("go","Go",style = "width:20%;")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    screenshot(id = "takemyscreenshot")
  })
  
  data <- data.frame(Period = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),Value = c(10,20,15,40,35,30))
  
  output$DF <- renderTable(data)
  output$plotDF <- renderPlot(ggplot(data, aes(Period,Value)) + geom_line())
  
  observeEvent(
    req(input$copy),
    writeLines(
      capture.output(
        write.table(
          x = data,
          sep = "\t",
          row.names = FALSE
        )
      ),
      "clipboard")
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This works well for downloading and I will use it. However it doesn't copy to the clipboard.